# Finding how many number of keys are there in a bucket

Tags: java, algorithm, data-structures, hashmap, hashtable

When multiple keys have same hash code, then a collision occurs. In that case, key-value entries are stored in linked list format mapping to a bucket. Now I wish to know how many such Map.Entry pair exists for given bucket. Is there any inbuilt java method that would help me to identify?

bucket1 ----> (10, 1) ---> (100, 2) --- Answer is 2 in this case.

bucket2 ----> (2, 1)  ---- Answer is 1.

bucket3  ----> (3, 5)  ---> (6, 10) ---> (9, 15) ---> (12, 18) ---- Answer in this case 4.

Any help towards this would be great.

Answer (score 2):

Unless you're using a collection as the value for your map, you won't be able to have more than one value for a particular bucket. Check what `put()` will do in the docs for [HashMap](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/HashMap.html#put(K,%20V))

Using a list as value for your map, you can try the following:

```
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.LinkedHashMap;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;

public class Playground {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Map<Integer, List<Pair>> map = new LinkedHashMap<Integer, List<Pair>>();

        map.put(1, Arrays.asList(new Pair(10, 1) , new Pair(100, 2)));
        map.put(2, Arrays.asList(new Pair(2, 1)));
        map.put(3, Arrays.asList(new Pair(3, 5), new Pair(6, 10), new Pair(9, 15), new Pair(12, 18)));

        for (Map.Entry<Integer, List<Pair>> entry : map.entrySet()) {
            System.out.println(String.format("Bucket %d has %d item(s)", entry.getKey(), entry.getValue().size()));
        }
    }
}

class Pair {
    Integer x;
    Integer y;

    Pair(Integer x, Integer y) {
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
    }
}
```

Your output will be the following:

```
Bucket 1 has 2 item(s)
Bucket 2 has 1 item(s)
Bucket 3 has 4 item(s)
```

Hope that helps

Comment: I don't think that answered my question (or maybe what I asked was not so clear). Lets assume that, I have a hashmap/hashtable with a bucket size of 5. In order to calculate the hashcode, I use mod 5 operator as hash function. The first 5 keys namely 1,2,3,4,5 will occupy buckets 1 through 5. When I insert key 6 along with some value, then it is added to bucket 1. Thus the size of bucket 1 is now 2. This is what I am looking for.

Comment: I see what you mean. I don't think the buckets' info will be exposed. Quickly checking the [source code](http://www.docjar.com/html/api/java/util/HashMap.java.html), the info you want is in there, just not publicly available.

Comment: Thanks, just to be on same page, are you referring to addEntry/createEntry methods?

Comment: The ```table``` attribute caught my attention first, but the methods you mentioned are also relevant. They end up modifying ```table```